# No Filter in Pixelmator

Tags: macos, pixelmator

I have been reading tutorials on Pixelmator where "Filter" is used. On all tutorials I have read there is a "Filter" option in the menu tab, but on mine "Filter" is missing. I tried searching for "Filter" in the help menu but there are no results.

[image]

Comment: did you check the preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Filter menu changed location in the recent update from v2 to v3. The filters are now in the **Effects Browser**.

A thread on [Pixelmator's support site](http://support.pixelmator.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8723) mentions the change.

Answer (score 1):

Pixelmator filters can now be found in the Effects browser -- see [this thread](http://support.pixelmator.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8723) for more information.